# Inner join by datetime columns

Tags: sql-server, join, datetime

I'm working in restructure a partinioned table so I have two tables with the same schema, for ensuring the insert process was executed succesfully without change some value i want to validate that the registers are equals into two tables.

This is the schema for two tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PerformanceSummary](
    [CountryName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [RegionName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CustomerName] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ProviderName] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Dia] [datetime] NULL,
    [CallsNumber] [float] NULL,
    [Charge] [float] NULL,
    [ChargeMinutes] [float] NULL,
    [Cost] [float] NULL,
    [CostMinutes] [float] NULL,
    [ACD] [float] NULL,
    [ASR] [float] NULL,
    [PDD] [float] NULL,
    [AAR] [float] NULL,
    [PSC] [float] NULL,
    [IsBillable] [int] NULL,
    [IsFailure] [int] NULL,
    [EsLatam] [bit] NULL,
    [Segmento] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Subsegmento] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CustomerBillingGroup] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [CustomerTrafficDesc] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [ProviderTrafficDesc] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [AccountManager] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [CustomerSLBR] [int] NULL,
    [ProviderAccountManager] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [ProviderSLBR] [int] NULL,
    [TipoTrafico] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ValorSemanaLaboral] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [ValorSemana] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [DayAndHour] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Clasificacion] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [GeographicZone] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [IsMerged] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Product] [varchar](55) NULL)
```

I'm triyng to execute the inner join in this way, but I obtained an issue:

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS bigint) AS Total
FROM PerformanceSummary PS
INNER JOIN PerformanceSummaryOLD PSO ON PS.DayAndHour = PSO.DayAndHour;
```

Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

How can I use the sentence COUNT when execute the inner join with datetime colums?

Comment: 1. Have you tried using COUNT_BIG?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-big-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16    2.  ... What exactly are you trying to verify?  It will only count the rows that have "Day And Hour" in both tables.  If one exists in one but not the other you won't see that.

Comment: Adding to what @JonathanFite said, rows will be counted more than once if multiple rows with the same `DayAndHour` value exist in both tables. Your query is suspect which may be the cause of the overflow.

Comment: @DanGuzman I follow your tips and exactly there are multiple rows with the same DayAndHour.
I want to verify that the records exist in the same way in both tables, sometimes when passing the information from one table to another the values are rounded if are decimal, float, etc

Comment: Hmm.  FLOAT is an imprecise datatype and should be discouraged.  You will need to find the set of keys that actually make a row unique so you can join on those instead of just a single datetime field.  Then to compare the FLOAT values, you could need to explicitly convert them to a decimal type with sufficient precision and then compare that.  Even comparing FLOAT to FLOAT if they look the same value can give a difference.

Answer (score 1):

count vs count_big - These functions differ only in the data types of their return values. COUNT_BIG always returns a bigint data type value. COUNT always returns an int data type value

check this out:

[Getting Starting with SQL COUNT() and COUNT_BIG() Functions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7319/sql-count-sql-count-big-functions/)

**basically if you want a bigint then use COUNT_BIG()**